# Generated WAR from my project ( Spring Boot )

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have already generated WAR from my project ( Spring Boot ), but after that i have changed some class of my source package, should i regenerate WAr or all i have to do is REPLACE .class in my WAR already generated  ??

Comment: It's much simpler and less risky to just re-execute the command generating the war. Your gradle or Maven build automates that.

Answer (score 0):

Go for a autmated build using Maven or Gradle and just do a complete rebuild of your war-file. This way you don't need to remember which classes to recompile.